# how to run clickhouse command without using the full path on mac

Tags: macos, path

I used brew to install clickhouse on OSX. To run clickhouse client I have to go `/Users/username/ClickHouse/build/programs` then `./clickhouse-client`

Is there a way I can just call clickhouse-client like on my linux box from anywhere in the system?

Currently im getting: `zsh: command not found: clickhouse-client` when I do not fully create a PATH.

Not really sure how to title this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to your path?

Since you mentioned using `zsh`

`echo "PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/ClickHouse/build/programs" >> ~/.zshrc`

This will append a new line to your .zshrc file. Close and re-open your terminal and you should be able to run clickhouse-client from anywhere.